# Survival analysis with ridge regression in R give same results with different random seeds

Tags: r, survival, ridge-regression

I am doing survival analysis using ridge regression. I'm using this R command:

```
coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ ridge(x1, x2, x3), data=DATA)
```

As far as I know, `lambda` (the regulation parameter) is estimated using cross validation, but then this R code should result in different results with different random seeds. But I got always the same coefficients; how can that happen?

Is `coxph(Surv()~.)` not a commonly used approach? Should I use `glmnet` or any other functions?

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you told us what package "ridge" is in.

Comment: Not knowing the above, one hypothesis is that the lambda sequence is a deterministic function of the entire data set.  So no matter how data is randomly allocated into the cross-validation sets, the same optimal lambda is chosen.  Then the model is refit using that lambda on the entire data set.

Comment: The R package I am using is "survival": http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/survival/html/ridge.html

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you linked combined with the method signature indicates that one chooses either `theta`, or it is chosen for you as a function of df.  If the latter is not specified, then it defaults to half the number of variables.

As far as I can tell, no cross-validation is occurring.  Why do you think that it is?